# WIFI not working Acer Aspire 3690 - BCM4311

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, 14.10, acer

WIFI still does not work, I tried several options. Is there something that will work 100%? I expected that linux will be easier!

I have LUBUNTU 14.10.

First I tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

And ... does not work.

Then I found the discussion to another command. For this to me disappeared and LAN, so that I was completely cut off from the internet and I had to reinstall the whole Lubuntu again :(

```
linux-headers-generic
```

On the contrary, the third time I found a script that ZEPRO works. And ... does not work.

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer b43-fwcutter
```

I tried to insert the * .inf driver of WIN7 for my wifi card via WINE - Ndiswrapper. Hardware not found, but the configuration - adding wifi, again nothing.

WIFI is working  and even finds SSID, but when I enter the correct WPA password, it does not connect WIFI. I also tried to reset the password of the  WIFI router , but the notebook does not connect via WIFI.

Comment: NEVER use the Windows drivers for a *nix system.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: Please avoid being offensive! "Linux really sucks" is not really what we want to read in here... I edited that away, because otherwise your question would not really attract the experts capable of solving your problem. But anyway: Welcome to AskUbuntu! :-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, ndiswrapper is not required. Let's remove it:

```
sudo apt-get purge ndiswrapper-common
sudo rm -rf /etc/ndiswrapper
```

Make sure that the needed driver is loaded:

```
lsmod | grep b43
```

If not, let's load it:

```
sudo modprobe b43
```

If it didn't load automatically, it is probably blacklisted somewhere; check:

```
ls /etc/modprobe.d
```

Once you post the result, we'll find and remove the blacklist.

Finally, be certain the wireless switch or key combination is set to enable wireless:

```
rfkill list all
```